# Escapes, Fades and Variable Colors [LESS]

Tags: css, variables, escaping, less

So working on a way to display color schemes from a **LESS** material color library. I want to be able to only change the color name and have all the colors change (50-900). I got the colors to work, **GREAT**, now just to get the text that sits on top to look more readable.

My idea was to use the contrast function within **LESS** to change the `color` depending on the `background-color` (*pretty basic right?*). I wrote the mixin and the `background-color` works but the `color` does not.

Two problems are happening.

**First:** 
When I pass it the escaped variables to output my code that I used for my `background-color`, it compiles ***WITH*** the **LESS** function included.

for example:

```
// Mixin
.mtrl-color-bg(@clrName, @clrValue) {
    @bgNestedVar: ~"@{clr-@{clrName}-@{clrValue}}";
    @clrContrast: contrast(@bgnNestedVar);
    background-color: @bgNestedVar;
    color: @clrContrast;
}
```

the above mixin will compile down to:

```
color: contrast(#Color);
```

**Second:**
If I try to *fance it up* and give the text a little sexy opacity goodness it decides that it doesn't even know what is going on and chooses to not compile at all.

Here's what I mean:

```
.mtrl-color-bg(@clrName, @clrValue) {
    @bgNestedVar: ~"@{clr-@{clrName}-@{clrValue}}";
    @clrContrast: fade(contrast(@bgnNestedVar), 65%);
    background-color: @bgNestedVar;
    color: @clrContrast;
}
```

[Here's a link to the codepen](http://codepen.io/zackgrrr/pen/VvGxNK) to see what I'm talking about.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

You guys the real MVP!

Comment: Those don't work because `@bgNestedVar` contains a string whereas the `fade`, `contrast` functions need a color as input. You should use `color(@bgNestedVar)` to convert the string into a color.

Comment: Thank you so much! works great!! I didnt even think about that.